# Composition of affine transformations.

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations

I am trying to do this exercise:

Let $f:\mathbb{R^3}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R^3}$ be a bijective affine transformation and $t_u:\mathbb{R^3}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R^3}$ a translation of vector $u$. Prove that $f \circ t_u \circ f$ is a translation $t_v$. Calculate $v$.

I have been thinking for a while and I suspect that this statement may not be true, but I have not been able to think of a counterexample. What makes me think that this statement may not be true is the fact that the linear application associated to $f \circ t_u \circ f$ may not be equal to the identity $id$, which is a characterisation of translations.

If anyone could give me a hint it would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: This is just false as written. You probably mean $f\circ t_u \circ f^{-1}$.

Comment: If that were the case it would be very easy to prove. Maybe there was a typo in the resource where I found this problem.

Comment: Consider the case of affine transformations of the real line and do the computation of $f\circ t_u \circ f$, where $f(x)=2x$. Where did you find this problem?

Comment: Ok, thank you! As to where I found the problem, it was a past paper of the subject of Linear Geometry taught at university.

Comment: Then it is just a typo.